# Api works on local but not in production (Django Rest + Flutter)

Tags: json, flutter, api, django-rest-framework, production

This is my first question in stackoverflow. I have always found answers searching but this time...

I have 2 json generated by Django Rest Framework, both of them have just strings...

The only thing i do is changing the local server urls for the production urls in my Flutter code.

While using local urls, i can display the data from both of them correctly inside a Flutter App.

While using production urls, only one is shown in the App and the other won't. Both jsons are rendered correctly in their production urls, i compared them with the local jsons urls and there is no difference at all.

Well, it is not really a question because i don't really know what to ask... just hoping some ideas... thanks.

Comment: Can you show the API code and the error String?

Comment: have you tested the production API's manually through a client like postman? Also if the API is not https, you may have to make some changes in your manifest as mentioned in below answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I tested both urls in postman, both of them are https. One shows [ { "string": "string", "string": "string" }] like it is, and the other just [ ], but it is  [ { "string": "string", "string": "string" }] The confusing part is that they are almost identical jsons... and more confusing is that both works correctly if testing in localhost

Answer (score 0):

make sure the AndroidManifest.xml includes the internet permission
if not, add this between `<Manifest>` and `<Application>`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks i added it before, the app was built and working. Since last week the problem started to happen, so i suspect it should be some configuration in the django server.